# Installing NVDIA-driver-525 fails, what am I missing?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, lenovo

Sorry, I am complete newbie regarding drivers and similar stuff. My Lenovo IdeaPad S145 laptop has the NVIDIA sticker, therefore I assume the hardware is capable of running NVIDIA drivers.I think, below screenshot proves that I am using the NVIDIA driver. Please correct me if I am being wrong here! [image]

But somehow it is not enough (not even after multiple reboot):
[image]

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04

What am I missing? Any suggestion is welcome, because even ChatGPT failed to give me a useful answer:-)

Comment: Do you have it installed. Older answer, you probably need newer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195774/nvidia-smi-command-not-found-but-gpu-works-fine

Comment: There are a couple of things that I can think of.  You can try running `sudo prime-select nvidia` and then reboot if your system has more than one video card.  You should also make sure that Secure Boot is disabled as the NVIDIA drivers are not signed.

Comment: According to the official nvidia website, that driver does support your video card.  https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/196723/en-us/ Turning off secure boot as @Terrance suggests is probably the first thing to try.